# How to create an ssl certificate for a localhost on my windows machine for Docker/portainer

Tags: docker, portainer

I am running Portainer on Docker on my windows machine, but the portainer on my localhost is not secure, so how do I create an ssl certificate locally and install it on portainer?... I'm still new to Docker/portainer, and I would love to have a step by step instructions

Thank you

Comment: This could probably be done by [generating a self-signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/8186898) and getting your browser [to accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7580508/8186898)

Comment: Portainer or any other technology should be on linux. On windows is just for proofs of concept. So, I recommend you not invest a lot of time in this. Do yo need the certificate as docker parameter on portainer run or just to access to the website?

Comment: @JRichardsz I need the certificate as docker parameter on portainer,

Comment: the comment of @Nino worked? You just need openssl